# Display constantly updating information in-place in command-line window using python?

Tags: python, command-line

I am essentially building a timer. I have a python script that monitors for an event and then prints out the seconds that have elapsed since that event.

Instead of an ugly stream of numbers printed to the command line, I would like to display only the current elapsed time "in-place"-- so that only one number is visible at any given time.

Is there a simple way to do this?

If possible I'd like to use built-in python modules. I'm on Windows, so simpler the better. (E.g. no X11).

Comment: You might also check out the curses library - it has advanced support for command line input & output. it should also work on Windows & *nix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outputting `\b` will move the output cursor left 1 cell, and outputting `\r` will return it to column 0. Make sure to flush the output often though.

Comment: I use sys.stdout.write('\r') in a loop! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use this: http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html